# Google Website Optimizer - Multi Variant Testing - Make a specific page a test page for two experiments?

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer

Im having a little issue with setting up Multi Variant Tests in Google Website Optimizer.

I wish to have two tests.
One being which is a header banner which appears on every page and the conversion for example would be if the visitor lands on the contact us page.
This was very easy to set up.

However when I intend to add another test, again this will be on a element which appears on every page and the conversion page is if the visitor lands on the checkout page.

But I am now having problems installing the control script.
I get the error:

```
Expected to find: }(function(){var k='0651116117',d=docum
Found on line 7: (function(){var k='2666211118',d=docum
```

Im assuming I have this error because I now have two control scripts in the header - one for each experiment. However I cannot combine each variation into just one experiment because each one is different and has a different conversion page?

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to have two tests. One being which is a header banner which appears on every page and the conversion for example would be if the visitor lands on the contact us page. This was very easy to set up.

[I wrote a blog post that explains how to setup 2+ GWO MVTs on the same page(s) which I think will answer this question](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/4/2/how-to-setup-two-gwo-mvt-tests-on-the-same-page).

However, the error that you display I suspect is due to some hackery on your part, because I don't think copying and pasting two control scripts to one header would cause an error, one test won't work, but there shouldn't be an error.